# Problems using .get to retrieve values from dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, for-loop, tkinter

I'm trying to write some loops to retrieve values from the dictionary and print them as checkbuttons.  Problem I'm having is that when I use the code as typed I get PY_VAR01, etc as my 'Names'

I know that i need to use .get() to get the value, but when I enter text=versions[2]['Name'].get() then my names appear as blank.  I've been searching and trying different things and can't get anything to work so help would be appreciated or if someone could point me in the right direction.

```
versions = { 1: {'Name': '5.11 - CO', 'Location': '#',
                 'Name': 'WS 2016 V1607', 'Location': '#',
                 'Name': 'Win 10 PRO V1803', 'Location': '#',
                 'Name': 'TEST 1', 'Location': '#',
                 'Name': 'TEST 2', 'Location': '#',
                 'Name': 'Test 3', 'Location': '#',
                 'Name': 'TEST 4', 'Location': '#',
                 'Name': 'TEST 5', 'Location': '#',
                 },
             2: {'Name':


# Version_5_5_EAC
v5_5_eac_options = Frame(optionsScreen)
v5_5_eac_options.grid()

for Name in versions:
    versions[1]['Name'] = Variable()
    l = Checkbutton(v5_5_eac_options, text=versions[1]['Name'], variable=versions[1]['Name'])
    l.pack()
```

I would like the Checkbox to print the associated name (ie. 5.5 - (EAC)) insteady of PY_VAR01

SO thanks to everyone who helped.  I mostly have it working now that I fixed the dictionary.

This is my updated code for the for loop but it's naming each checkbox with the same variable so I need to mess with it some more.

```
for Name in versions[1]:
    var = Variable()
    l = Checkbutton(v5_5_eac_options, text=versions[1][4]['Name'], variable=var)
    l.pack()
```

Comment: Your `versions` dict literal has a lot of duplicate keys; only the last value for a given key is actually stored in the dictionary.

Comment: That should either be a list of dictionaries, or you should make names and locations the keys and values of the dictionary.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `for Name in versions:` loop? You never use the `Name` variable, you've hard-coded `versions[1]` everywhere.

Comment: Why are you assigning to `version[1]['Name']`? That will replace whatever was in the `versions` dictionary.

Comment: There is no `versions[2]` so `text=versions[2]['Name'].get()` isn't going to work.

Comment: @martineau I think he just posted the beginning of the dictionary, notice that there's a comma at the end and no closing brace.

Comment: There are 8 "versions" I just didn't want to post 60 lines of code.  Each one follows the same structure.

Comment: @Barmar: Perhaps, but even with a close `}`, there's no `versions[2]` — some maybe at least part of the problem is the data-structure is wrong.

Comment: @Jordan: You wouldn't need tp post that many lines to make `version[2]` valid. What's needed when asking questions here is a [mre].

Comment: ```2: {'Name': '5.5 - S', 'Location': '#',
                'Name': 'WS 2012 RS', 'Location': '#',
                'Name': 'Win 10 PRO V1607', 'Location': '#',
                'Name': 'TEST 1', 'Location': '#',
                ```

Comment: @Jordan: As others have previously mentioned, you can't have duplicate keys in a dictionary.

Comment: Ok, i added the second version. I think maybe I'm doing the dictionary wrong.  Going to go back and edit it as suggested.

Comment: You still have duplicate keys in the nested dictionaries.

Comment: @Barmar perhaps you should post an answer, you seem to have this solved and can directly help without having to dig through comments.

Comment: @economy Someone else already posted an answer. I can't figure out what the rest of the code is supposed to do, so I wouldn't know what to put in the answer.

Comment: You was a minute ahead, so go on repost, maybe slightly differently

Comment: @Barmar I redid the dictionary as suggested, not sure what your problem is..the first comment saying i added the second version was in reference to versions = {2: since people thought they didn't exist.

Comment: You shouldn't change the question to match the answer. Now the answer makes no sense.

Comment: I attempted to answer the root of the original question, i.e. how to set up a dictionary with lists and access each element, but the question has now shifted too far to be helpful to anyone else searching for an answer to the same issue. The question either needs to be edited to provide a minimal reproducible example with a clear issue, or be closed.

Comment: sorry, i don't know how else to post the code i edited for others to see because the comments don't allow it.  I will go back and put the original code at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have to use get.

More, when an key, say Name is repeated in dictionary constructor, only one value is preserved.

```
versions = {1: {'Name': '5.5 - (EAC)', 'Location': '#',
                'Name': 'WS 2012 RS', 'Location': '#',
                'Name': 'Win 10 PRO V1607', 'Location': '#',
                'Name': 'TEST 1', 'Location': '#',
                'Name': 'TEST 2', 'Location': '#',
                'Name': 'Test 3', 'Location': '#',
                'Name': 'TEST 4', 'Location': '#',
                'Name': 'TEST 5', 'Location': '#'}}


print (versions)
```

results in

```
{1: {'Name': 'TEST 5', 'Location': '#'}}
```

So you should first modify your data structure, e.g. nesting arrays like

```
versions = {1: [{'Name': '5.5 - (EAC)', 'Location': '#'},
                {'Name': 'WS 2012 RS', 'Location': '#'},
                 ...],
            2:...
            }
```

Now, to access say the fifth element of the list of Names, Test 2, we add index 4 (python lists start from 0)

```
text = version[1][4]['Name']
```

To render the last version only, something like

```
for record in versions[-1]:
    record['variable'] = IntVar()
    l = Checkbutton(v5_5_eac_options, text=record['Name'],   variable=record['variable']
    l.pack()
```

PS. I see question being updated to match the suggested answer

Comment: just trying to understand what the [4] is referencing.  Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I get this error though.  line 279, in <module>
    versions[1]['Name'] = Variable()
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

Comment: @JordanHawkes See the last line of the answer. You need to index the list of dictionaries.

Comment: @JordanHawkes looks like you did not copy [4]

Comment: Create new variable var and put it in variable=var instead of variable=versions[1]['Name']

Comment: check some tk tutorial for button syntax https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_checkbutton.htm

Comment: i'm almost getting there haha thanks for your help so far

Comment: welcome, yet you accepted the duplicate, well, marginally different, answer from economy

Comment: only reason being that i can't get yours to work in terms of the checkbutton (most likely cuz i'm dumb so not your fault) his answer got the closest but it's still printing both versions and i only want it to print one version at a time so tyring to play around with it

Comment: ah, I see. Not sure how he helped. Error was because you kept all expression (without 4) while you should provide a variable.  variable=var instead of variable=versions[1]['Name']

Comment: yes but the only problem is that when i do it as you suggested (adding variable=var and setting text=versions[1][4] is that it is naming all of them "Test 2" i think i need to iterate another loop rather than hard coding 4 which is what's causing the issue so i'm going to play with it but i wanted each checkbutton to have the appropriate name not the same name.  ANyway yes you helped a lot sorry i accepted your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks. Yup you need a loop like he suggested 
    `for record in version[2]: print(record['Name'])`

Comment: And you still have create a variable for each button. You cannot pass a text when tk expects a variable

Answer (score 1):

First, set up the dictionary as key: list of dictionary pairs:

```
versions = {
    1: [
        {'Name': '5.5 - (EAC)', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'WS 2012 RS', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'Win 10 PRO V1607', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'TEST 1', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'TEST 2', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'Test 3', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'TEST 4', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'TEST 5', 'Location': '#'}
    ],
    2: [
        {'Name': '5.5 - S', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'WS 2012 RS', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'Win 10 PRO V1607', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'TEST 1', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'TEST 2', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'Test 3', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'TEST 4', 'Location': '#'},
        {'Name': 'TEST 5', 'Location': '#'}
    ]
}
```

Then, you can access each `Name` using a nested for loop:

```
for index, version in in versions.items():
    for record in version:
        print(record['Name'])
```

Since I'm not sure what you're doing with each `index` or `record` in this dictionary, you'll need to map it to a checkbox however you're using those in your application.

EDIT:

You want to have two separate for loops based on your edit.

```
for record in versions[1]:
    print record['Name']
```

and

```
for record in versions[2]:
    print record['Name']
```

Comment: when i do this it says that for record in index: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: edited to fix, dictionary elements can be accessed with `items()`

Comment: ahh damn so i'm super close.  The only issue now is that the for loop is printing ALL of the Names (like for version 1 and 2.  I only want it to print the Names for version 1.  A separate for loop would be used for version 2 because they are displayed in different Frames.  Also sorry that i edited the question, it was the only way to post the code.  Will go back to put the original code so that your anser matches.  Thanks for all of your help so far.

Comment: edited back to original question, just need to figure out how to only print one version instead of two.  Gonna play with some stuff.  Thanks agian.